# My C++ simulator crashes the terminal

Tags: c++, windows, crash

My code crashes the terminal each time I execute it. I have tried it with Geany and Visual C++ for debugging and it also crashes when just going through cmd prompt.

I got rid of all the bugs using the debugger, but it didn't help. I am supposed to be creating a simulator of a cache, and looking for hits and misses using random numbers, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int r = 8192;
const int c = 3;
const int r1 = 262144;
int i;
int j;
int k;

int max;
int min;
int numberW0;
int index_max;
int index_min;
int numberX0;
int tag_max;
int tag_min;
int numberY0;
unsigned int data_max;
int data_min;
int numberZ0;

int numberW1;
int index_max1;
int index_min1;
int numberX1;
int tag_max1;
int tag_min1;
int numberY1;
unsigned int data_max1;
int data_min1;
int numberZ1;

int numberW2;
int index_max2;
int index_min2;
int numberX2;
int tag_max2;
int tag_min2;
int numberY2;
unsigned int data_max2;
int data_min2;
int numberZ2;

int numberW3;
int index_max3;
int index_min3;
int numberX3;
int tag_max3;
int tag_min3;
int numberY3;
unsigned int data_max3;
int data_min3;
int numberZ3;

int numberW4;
int index_max4;
int index_min4;
int numberX4;
int tag_max4;
int tag_min4;
int numberY4;
unsigned int data_max4;
int data_min4;
int numberZ4;

double new_valid = 0;
double new_tag = -9999999999;
double new_data = -9999999999;

double tag_value;
int s;
int t;
double block0;
double block1;
double block2;
double block3;
int v;
double levBlock;

fstream armRes;

int main()
{
    double way0 [r][c];  //declaration of the arrays
    double way1 [r][c];
    double way2 [r][c];
    double way3 [r][c];

    double lev2[r1][c];

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) // initialization of the arrays
    {
        way0[i][0] = new_valid;
        way0[i][1] = new_tag;
        way0[i][2] = new_data;

        way1[i][0] = new_valid;
        way1[i][1] = new_tag;
        way1[i][2] = new_data;

        way2[i][0] = new_valid;
        way2[i][1] = new_tag;
        way2[i][2] = new_data;

        way3[i][0] = new_valid;
        way3[i][1] = new_tag;
        way3[i][2] = new_data;  
    }

    for (j = 0; j < r1; j++)
    {
        lev2[j][0] = new_valid;
        lev2[j][1] = new_tag;
        lev2[j][2] = new_data;
    }


    srand (time(0));  // random number generator seed


    int max = r;
    int min = 0;
    int max1 = r1;
    int min1 = 0;
    int numberW0 = (rand()%max+min+1); // number of entires to populate way0

    for (k = 0; k <= numberW0; k++)
    {
        int index_max = 8192;
        int index_min = 0;

        numberX0 = rand()%index_max+index_min+1; // random index to use

        int tag_max = 32768;
        int tag_min = 0;
        numberY0 = rand()%tag_max+tag_min+1; // random tag for the index

        unsigned int data_max = 429496729; // random data for the index
        int data_min = 0;
        numberZ0 = rand()%data_max+data_min+1;

        way0 [numberX0][0] = 1;
        way0 [numberX0][1] = numberY0;
        way0 [numberX0][2] = numberZ0;
    }

    int numberW1 = (rand()%max+min+1); // number of entires to populate way1

    for (k = 0; k <= numberW1; k++)
    {
        int index_max1 = 8192;
        int index_min1 = 0;

        numberX1 = rand()%index_max1+index_min1+1; // random index to use

        int tag_max1 = 32768;
        int tag_min1 = 0;
        numberY1 = rand()%tag_max1+tag_min1+1; // random tag for the index

        unsigned int data_max1 = 429496729; // random data for the index
        int data_min1 = 0;
        numberZ1 = rand()%data_max1+data_min1+1;

        way1 [numberX1][0] = 1;
        way1 [numberX1][1] = numberY1;
        way1 [numberX1][2] = numberZ1;
    }

    int numberW2 = (rand()%max+min+1); // number of entires to populate way2

    for (k = 0; k <= numberW2; k++)
    {
        int index_max2 = 8192;
        int index_min2 = 0;

        numberX2 = rand()%index_max2+index_min2+1; // random index to use

        int tag_max2 = 32768;
        int tag_min2 = 0;
        numberY2 = rand()%tag_max2+tag_min2+1; // random tag for the index

        unsigned int data_max2 = 429496729; // random data for the index
        int data_min2 = 0;
        numberZ2 = rand()%data_max2+data_min2+1;

        way2 [numberX2][0] = 1;
        way2 [numberX2][1] = numberY2;
        way2 [numberX2][2] = numberZ2;
    }

    int numberW3 = (rand()%max+min+1); // number of entires to populate way3

    for (k = 0; k <= numberW3; k++)
    {
        int index_max3 = 8192;
        int index_min3 = 0;

        numberX3 = rand()%index_max3+index_min3+1; // random index to use

        int tag_max3 = 32768;
        int tag_min3 = 0;
        numberY3 = rand()%tag_max3+tag_min3+1; // random tag for the index

        unsigned int data_max3 = 429496729; // random data for the index
        int data_min3 = 0;
        numberZ3 = rand()%data_max3+data_min3+1;

        way3 [numberX3][0] = 1;
        way3 [numberX3][1] = numberY3;
        way3 [numberX3][2] = numberZ3;
    }

    int numberW4 = (rand()%max1+min1+1); // number of entires to populate level 2

    for (k = 0; k <= numberW4; k++)
    {
        int index_max4 = r1;
        int index_min4 = 0;

        numberX4 = rand()%index_max4+index_min4+1; // random index to use

        int tag_max4 = 32768;
        int tag_min4 = 0;
        numberY4 = rand()%tag_max4+tag_min4+1; // random tag for the index

        unsigned int data_max4 = 429496729; // random data for the index
        int data_min4 = 0;
        numberZ4 = rand()%data_max4+data_min4+1;

        lev2 [numberX4][0] = 1;
        lev2 [numberX4][1] = numberY4;
        lev2 [numberX4][2] = numberZ4;
    }

    armRes.open("C:\\Users\\Max\\Documents\\CSIT4\\Project\\Practice\\ARMresults.txt", ios::out | ios::app );

    for (t = 0; t<= 15000; t++)
    {
        int tag_value = rand()%32768+0+1;

        for (s = 0; s <= r; s++)
        {
            block0 = way0 [s][1];
            block1 = way1 [s][1];
            block2 = way2 [s][1];
            block3 = way3 [s][1];

            if (tag_value == block0)
            {
                armRes << "L1 Hit (Way 0) -- AT INDEX: " << s << endl;
            }

            else if (tag_value == block1)
            {
                armRes << "L1 Hit (Way1) -- AT INDEX: " << s << endl;
            }   

            else if (tag_value == block2)
            {
                armRes << "L1 Hit (Way2) -- AT INDEX: " << s << endl;
            }   
            else if (tag_value == block3)
            {
                armRes << "L1 Hit (Way3) -- AT INDEX: " << s << endl;
            }

            else 
            {
                for (v = 0; v <= r1; v++)
                {
                    double levBlock = lev2 [v][1];

                    if (tag_value == levBlock)
                    {
                        armRes << "L2 Hit -- AT INDEX: " << v << endl;
                    }

                    else

                    {
                        armRes << "Cache Miss For Tag: " << tag_value << endl;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    armRes.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I no longer have any academic help

Comment: So try to find where in particular it crashes and list only code relevant to that section.

Comment: You call this c++ ? It's more like C code for me

Comment: What input are you feeding it? What is the expected result? Where in the program does it crash? A lot of relevant information is missing.

Comment: Hint: Your bug is in the line `numberX0 = rand()%index_max+index_min+1;`.

Comment: SORRY! Didnt realize what exactly I would need to tell you all. My problem is i do not know where it crashes. I used a debugger, removed all the bugs, and then the problems came. *** Just been back to my code, If i comment out everything after and including the line that opens the file stream, it still crashes, so the issue i beleive is in the first half of this code

Comment: Its not being given any info as a parameter, its creating 5 arrays, filling them with random numbers (although there are set ranges for these numbers), i am then generating 15,000 random numbers to see if they match any of the numbers in the existing 5 arrays

Comment: In reply to Russell Zahniser --- I have used that specific line in other programs, and have no issue, and it hasn't crashed

Comment: one of the most horrible programs I've ever seen

Comment: Thanks for the comments regarding how the code looks, but this is the least of my concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue right away:  You are more than likely blowing out the stack with the memory taken up by those arrays in main().  Since you're using Visual C++, I can assume the following:

```
double way0 [r][c];  //declaration of the arrays
double way1 [r][c];
double way2 [r][c];
double way3 [r][c];
double lev2[r1][c];
```

Given this:

```
const int r = 8192;
const int c = 3;
const int r1 = 262144;
```

If the sizeof(double) == 8, then that is over 7,000,000 bytes of stack required to hold those arrays.  The default stack is (I believe) 1 megabyte (maybe 2 megabytes, can't recall off the top of my head), but nowhere near close to 7 megabytes.

Therefore you need to use dynamic allocation to create those arrays.  The simplest way is to use a std::vector and size accordingly.

```
#include <vector>
//...
typedef std::vector<double> Double1D;
typedef std::vector<Double1D> Double2D;

Double2D way0(r, Double1D(c));
Double2D way1(r, Double1D(c));
Double2D way2(r, Double1D(c));
Double2D way3(r, Double1D(c));
Double2D lev2(r1, Double1D(c));
```

This now creates the data away from the stack and instead onto the heap.  The rest of the code should be able to compile with no further changes.

Note that I did not check any of the array indices you're using in the rest of your program, so you could still have an array access violation somewhere in the rest of the code.  Others have commented that you do have some index boundary issues using rand(), but at least you won't run into stack space issues.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as soon as I can. I am assuming you mean that if i use dynamic allocation, all other code that accesses these arrays will also need to be changed to reflect the fact it uses dynamic allocation?

Comment: The rest of the code doesn't change at all.  That's the good thing.  The only thing you're changing is that the memory that used to be placed on the stack is now moved to the heap.  The vector handles this automatically, and you access the data using the same syntax as arrays (using [][]).

Comment: You could alternatively use the `static` keyword to statically allocate the arrays.  That's not generally considered good practice, but it's harmless when only used in main() and is more efficient than using vectors.

Comment: Harry Johnston - Do you have an example of how I could do this?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry, thought I would tag you so you can see my previous comment above

Comment: @HarryJohnston I would like to add - I simply added static in front of the array declarations, and now the program does not crash, but it has been running for about 10 minutes as has not yet stopped, also, the file the program creates is already over 1GB in size! How is this even possible, its only outputting single lines of code in a  plain text file

Comment: You're outputting 122 million lines, at roughly 30 characters per line, so that's about 3.4GB of text.